# Trying to close clearly off-topic question, close vote expires?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I have voted to close as off-topic (title says it all...) this question several times now: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45493456/1717300

Why has this failed? Has my close vote expired? Have others found it is in fact on-topic? The question seems unambiguously off-topic to me, so I am a bit curious what is happening.

Comment: Meta effect: the post has now been deleted.

Comment: That it didn't get closed is a symptom of the *the close process being broken*. *Far* more off-topic questions are posted than can be handled by users who actually vote-to-close. This will only get even worse as time goes on. The only ways this might get better are to A) reduce the number of bad questions (some effort by SE is on-going to help this; I'm hopeful, but pessimistic); B) Increase the ability of users who do vote-to-close to actually get questions closed (many feature request proposals, none moved forward); and/or increase the proportion of users who vote-to-close (unlikely).

Comment: What's also a problem, is that some users dig out certain categories of questions, such as recommendation questions, and ask why their question was closed while those others weren't.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate. Let's see if this vote expires :-)

Comment: This is not a good duplicate.  It describes an outdated process in both the question and the answer (the idea that aged close votes cannot be recast, which has changed since then).

Comment: As a user who mostly asks questions (and answers few), I sometimes ask a bad question without realizing it. Once it a receives a single vote to close, no one else is likely to see it. After I edit the question (to correct the cause for the vote), still no one sees it. So, basically why even bother? I generally just re-ask the same question to avoid this broken pitfall of SO. My point being, basically one vote is all that is needed to effectively kill a question anyway. Might as well just reduce the number of votes needed to close. As a question asker, this makes zero difference to me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can check the [post timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45493456/timeline) to see what has happened. It has been sent to the Close Votes review queue **five times**, and has failed to be closed each time.

Four out of those five times, no-one else reviewed the post at all (presumably it was just buried in the queue and never got seen). The first time, in August, it gained [one close vote](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/16927452) from the queue before ageing away.

At no point has anyone ever voted to leave it open, though. It's simply the case that no-one has got to the post and closed it before all the votes age away ([after 14 days if the question has less than 100 views, and after 4 days if there are more than 100 views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/336144)) and it is removed from the queue.

Answer (score 5):

This is a weakness in the SO user moderator system: it is often problematic to close off-topic posts that use tags that not many users visit.

The best way to moderate such posts is to (of course) cast your close vote, leave a comment for the OP if needed, then visit the [SO Close Vote Reviewers chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). One of the reasons that chat exists is scenarios just like this one.

This chat room has various formalities for how you can ask other user moderators to help with closing off-topic posts. More info in the [chat room FAQ](https://socvr.org/).